# How to add middleware that truly comes before Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Given `config.ru`

```
# Special care taken to load before even requiring the rails app
require './test_middleware.rb'
use TestMiddleware

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

and

`test_middleware.rb`

```
require 'byebug'

class TestMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    debugger
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

When I run `rackup config.ru` and make a request, my env hash is already massive and filled with all sorts of rails related things, like `#<ActionDispatch::Journey::Path::Pattern:0x007f814c4a9e60`. `#<Rails::Initializable::Initializer:0x007f814d1d0b20`. Pretty printing the env takes seconds, there are thousands upon thousands of objects in there.

I've put my middleware in what seems to the the highest possible place in the stack. Ive also tried using `config.middleware.unshift TestMiddleware` such that `rake middleware` indicate it as being at the top of the stack, but the results were the same. How can I get at a request env before its been touched by Rails at all? How does rails even do all this before `@app.call`? (Ive confirmed that `@app` here is an instance of the Rails application)

Comment: I can’t reproduce this, the `env ` hash just has the stuff you’d expect from rack when I try. What versions of Rails / Rack / Ruby etc are you using?

Comment: @matt currently away from my computer, but I'm using Rails 5 beta 3 (for no particular reason other than it was already there when I generated the test app) and puma web server (since I have to use a server supported by faye-websockets-ruby). I'll report back with specific versions asap.

Comment: To clarify though, the top level keys of the env hash were mostly typical. The rails artifacts o found were deeply nested and revealed by pretty printing the hash

Comment: I think I’ve reproduced it using Puma as the server. Puma seems to add a `puma.config` entry to the `env` hash that contains all the extra stuff. If you ignore that you get pretty much the same basic hash as you’d expect.

Comment: Yep, it was `puma.config`!